# Get JNDI resources programatically in spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jndi

I have a Tomcat servlet container that has a list of `DataSource`s managed by Tomcat's connection pool. From my Spring application (Spring 3.2.3) I would like to get one of these datasources on runtime, something like:

```
public class MyService {
    @Autowired 
    private JndiObjectLocator jndiLocator;

    public void myMethod(String jndiName) {
        DataSource myDataSource = jndiLocator.locate(jndiName);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Why do you need a runtime lookup, why is it you cannot do this in configuration?

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: @M.Deinum Because I will have around 20 DataSources (original bad design) and I do not want to `@Autowire` 20 Resources and do 20 switch-cases. Also the number of DataSources will increase (probably once per year)

Comment: @Stefoan The problem is: how to do that in Spring?

Comment: And why couldn't you define all of them in a spring configuration and use a reference to the `BeanFactory` (or `ApplicationContext`) to do the lookup? No need for a switch/if-then-else construction. Also if those 20 datasources are about multitenancy support you might want to have a [look at this](http://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/one-application-per-client-database/) which would make it completly transparant for your application.

Comment: @M.Deinum I really appreciate your comments. `BeanFactory` is really a way to go (I am new to Spring), although all `DataSource`s have to be defined in the beans configuration. My application is not multitenancy, as one user has access to all databases. Your last comment deserves to be converted to an answer (and upvoted) (please do that). Do you have any ideas on how do that without defining them specifically in any files in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do a JNDI lookup in your code, you can use the `JndiDataSourceLookup` for that and call the `getDataSource()` method.

```
public class MyService {
    @Autowired 
    private JndiDataSourceLookup lookup;

    public void myMethod(String jndiName) {
        DataSource myDataSource = lookup.getDataSourcejndiName);
    }
}
```

Another option would be to make your bean aware of the `BeanFactory` and retrieve the `DataSource` from there.

```
public class MyService {
    @Autowired 
    private BeanFactory factory;

    public void myMethod(String jndiName) {
        DataSource myDataSource = factory.getBean(jndiName, DataSource.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: `JndiDataSourceLookup` is exactly I was looking for and works perfectly.